# How do I change properties of a UIButton that is created through storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ExerciseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var numRepsTracker: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var setsLeft: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var downArrow: UIButton! 
   
}
```

I want to change the image of my UIButton to an image of my choosing, but I don't think I can via Interface Builder. Is there a way to write the code programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. You can use `setImage` method of UIButton class.

[UIButton.setImage - Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage)

`downArrow.setImage(image, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change in the interface builder. In the right panel (the attributes inspector), you can customize most of its properties. This includes the image.

<kbd>[image: Image dropdown selection in attributes inspector]</kbd>

But, if you want to do it in code, you can just put this inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
downArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "YourImageName"), for: .normal)
```